# etc/update-motd.d added script which executes. But after change the old version is being executed

Tags: login, login-screen, motd

My script executes OK. But when I altered it on login the old one is still executing instead of the amended one. Do I need to refresh/restart something (except system :) ) for my changes to be effective? (I ssh connect)

Comment: Your question is rather clear; details in the title do **not** always show with some browser/setups (*not everyone uses large PCs or large screens!*) so you mention a script; no error message, and a rather unclear problem or question (just a *Do I need to refresh/restart* without a why that relates in your question text).

Comment: @guiverc no errors simply after change the old version is still executing instead of the new one.

Comment: AFAIK the contents should be updated automatically on each ssh login - provided you haven't altered the default /etc/pam.d/sshd file. If you want further help, I suggest you edit your question to include both the contents *and name* of the script, and the output of `grep motd /etc/pam.d/sshd`